# How to find Latitude and Longitude from Address

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I am using Address to get Latitude and Longitude of that location, but it always returns null...

I am passing address like this: `1701 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View CA 94043`

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
try {                                                
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(strNewClientCompleteAddress, 1);
    if ((addresses != null) && (addresses.size() > 0)) {
        Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
        lat = fetchedAddress.getLatitude();
        lng = fetchedAddress.getLongitude();
        Log.v("try-if", "ok great work");
    } else {
        Log.v("try-else", "something wrong");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.v("catch", "Could not get address....!");
}                           
strLat = String.valueOf(lat);
Log.v("lat:", strLat);
strLng = String.valueOf(lng);
Log.v("lng:", strLng);
```

and **Log** says

```
V/strNewClientCompleteAddress:(1466): 1701 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View CA 94043
V/try-else(1466): something wrong
V/lat:(1466): 0.0
V/lng:(1466): 0.0
```

Manifest **permissions**:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: According to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html): "Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available." Make sure your network connexion is available

Comment: Can you debug your application and check what is value in fetchedAddress.?

Comment: @BlueGreen i already posted Log report V/strNewClientCompleteAddress:(1466): 1701 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View CA 94043

Comment: I had a similar problem. Rebooting the phone fixed everything :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, there nothing is wrong in code.

I got below log.

```
02-21 06:21:16.036: V/try-if(18306): ok great work
02-21 06:21:16.036: V/lat:(18306): 37.4235981
02-21 06:21:16.036: V/lng:(18306): -122.0871014
```

Please make sure you have import below class.

```
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
```

**The Geocoder class backend is only present on Google-approved devices. So the lookup will basically fail on any device that doesn't have GMail/Market/Maps on it.**

Also check is internet is working in device..

**Note :** Sometime Geocoder service is not working in background because its killed due to less memory or task manager. It will start again after reboot device.

Comment: don't know why i am facing this issue, can you share your demo code with me, so i will try that ..

Comment: I just copied your code and didn't change anything...try in different device and different address.

Comment: are you serious ? i am still not getting latitude and longitude ... can you show me your activity code .. may be i will get some difference

Comment: Did you try in different real device, is your internet working ?

Comment: are you testing in device or emulator ?

Comment: Just check at once in Google API emulator, it is also working in Google API emulator at my side.

Comment: @Sun hi, when I tested in samsung device I got, **service not available** but it is working fine after reboot device, so please reboot your device at once.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you set the necessary permissions, e.g.:

   > android.permission.INTERNET"
2. Have you added Google Play Services?
3. What return Geocoder.isPresent() method? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#isPresent%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use Google Api https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

directly, you will get JSON list with locations.

this approach is not dependent on Play Services on phone, but uses Maps API Key